# Как подключить view файл в множество других файлов?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть файл, который называется menu.php, в нем хранится меню для пользователя
Я хочу подключать его в другие файлы, как это можно сделать?

На данный момент делаю так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это не правильно и темболее я хочу его подключать к многим action. 
Как можно было бы это сделать правильно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кто давал право использовать echo в экшенах контроллера?

Comment: Вообще лучше для меню использовать виджет.
И просто прописывать его в нужном месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтоб зарендерить меню на страницы его нужно не в контроллере добавлять, а в вашем шаблоне, `layouts/main`.

Если вы хотите чтоб меню отображалось не на всех страницах можете сделать отдельные шаблоны, которые уже можете менять на нужных вам страницах в контроллере `$this->layout = 'layoutName';`.